# Get the MD5 hash of big files in Python

Tags: python, md5, hashlib

I have used *[hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html)* (which replaces *[md5](https://docs.python.org/2/library/md5.html)* in Python 2.6/3.0), and it worked fine if I opened a file and put its content in the [`hashlib.md5()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) function.

The problem is with very big files that their sizes could exceed the RAM size.

How can I get the MD5 hash of a file without loading the whole file into memory?

Comment: I would rephrase: "How to get the MD5 has of a file without loading the whole file to memory?"

Comment: starting with 3.11 `hashlib` gained the `file_digest` function which appears to take the hazzle to write chunking boilerplate from you https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.file_digest

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Break the file into 8192-byte chunks (or some other multiple of 128 bytes) and feed them to MD5 consecutively using `update()`.

This takes advantage of the fact that MD5 has 128-byte digest blocks (8192 is 128×64). Since you're not reading the entire file into memory, this won't use much more than 8192 bytes of memory.

In Python 3.8+ you can do

```
import hashlib
with open("your_filename.txt", "rb") as f:
    file_hash = hashlib.md5()
    while chunk := f.read(8192):
        file_hash.update(chunk)
print(file_hash.digest())
print(file_hash.hexdigest())  # to get a printable str instead of bytes
```

Comment: You can just as effectively use a block size of any multiple of 128 (say 8192, 32768, etc.) and that will be much faster than reading 128 bytes at a time.

Comment: Thanks jmanning2k for this important note, a test on 184MB file takes (0m9.230s, 0m2.547s, 0m2.429s) using (128, 8192, 32768), I will use 8192 as the higher value gives non-noticeable affect.

Comment: If you can, you should use [`hashlib.blake2b`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#blake2) instead of `md5`. Unlike MD5, [BLAKE2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAKE_(hash_function)#BLAKE2) is secure, and it's even faster.

Comment: @Boris, you can't actually say that BLAKE2 is secure. All you can say is that it hasn't been broken yet.

Comment: @vy32 you can't say it's definitely going to be broken either. We'll see in 100 years, but it's at least better than MD5 which is definitely insecure.

Comment: @Boris, I didn't mean to imply to you that it's going to be broken. All we know is that it hasn't been broken yet. MD5 being "broken" is a funny thing. It's still not susceptible to the second pre-image attack, which is why it's still widely used in digital forensics.

Answer (score 237):

You need to read the file in chunks of suitable size:

```
def md5_for_file(f, block_size=2**20):
    md5 = hashlib.md5()
    while True:
        data = f.read(block_size)
        if not data:
            break
        md5.update(data)
    return md5.digest()
```

Note: Make sure you open your file with the 'rb' to the open - otherwise you will get the wrong result.

So to do the whole lot in one method - use something like:

```
def generate_file_md5(rootdir, filename, blocksize=2**20):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    with open( os.path.join(rootdir, filename) , "rb" ) as f:
        while True:
            buf = f.read(blocksize)
            if not buf:
                break
            m.update( buf )
    return m.hexdigest()
```

The update above was based on [the comments provided by Frerich Raabe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131220/get-the-md5-hash-of-big-files-in-python#comment8038619_1131255) - and I tested this and found it to be correct on my Python 2.7.2 Windows installation

I cross-checked the results using the [jacksum](http://www.jonelo.de/java/jacksum/) tool.

```
jacksum -a md5 <filename>
```

Comment: What's important to notice is that the file which is passed to this function must be opened in binary mode, i.e. by passing `rb` to the `open` function.

Comment: This is a simple addition, but using `hexdigest` instead of `digest` will produce a hexadecimal hash that "looks" like most examples of hashes.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if len(data) < block_size: break`?

Comment: Erik, no, why would it be? The goal is to feed all bytes to MD5, until the end of the file. Getting a partial block does not mean all the bytes should not be fed to the checksum.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: Thanks. I always forget that and then my code blows up on Windows machines.

Comment: Mandatory to get the right hashsum: Reset the position where to read from! I.e. by adding `f.seek(0)` to the first line of the first algorithm. Otherwise the start location is unknown and may be in the middle of the file.

Comment: @user2084795 `open` __always__ opens a fresh file handle with the position set to the start of the file, _(unless you open a file for append)._

Comment: still works for me in 2023.  sadly I don't have python 3.11 yet on _this_ system, so I can't use the new filepointer in `hashlib`. But `python 3.6.8`  `[GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-18)] on linux` reports the same as `md5sum` when i use the above python code and `hexdigest`

note, I only tested against a 1gb file, because I don't feel like waiting.  but I did use the `2**20` blocksize.  I'll be back later (or edit comment) if this fails on the 200gb files i need to work with.

Answer (score 125):

#### Python < 3.7

```
import hashlib

def checksum(filename, hash_factory=hashlib.md5, chunk_num_blocks=128):
    h = hash_factory()
    with open(filename,'rb') as f: 
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(chunk_num_blocks*h.block_size), b''): 
            h.update(chunk)
    return h.digest()
```

#### Python 3.8 and above

```
import hashlib

def checksum(filename, hash_factory=hashlib.md5, chunk_num_blocks=128):
    h = hash_factory()
    with open(filename,'rb') as f: 
        while chunk := f.read(chunk_num_blocks*h.block_size): 
            h.update(chunk)
    return h.digest()
```

#### Original post

If you want a more Pythonic (no `while True`) way of reading the file, check this code:

```
import hashlib

def checksum_md5(filename):
    md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(filename,'rb') as f: 
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(8192), b''): 
            md5.update(chunk)
    return md5.digest()
```

Note that the `iter()` function needs an empty byte string for the returned iterator to halt at EOF, since `read()` returns `b''` (not just `''`).

Comment: Better still, use something like `128*md5.block_size` instead of `8192`.

Comment: mrkj: I think it's more important to pick your read block size based on your disk and then to ensure that it's a multiple of `md5.block_size`.

Comment: the `b''` syntax was new to me. Explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6269785/1174169).

Comment: @Harvey Is there any rule of thumb for common disk block sizes? Or otherwise any recommendations for determining optimal block size?

Comment: @ThorSummoner: Not really, but from my working finding optimum block sizes for flash memory, I'd suggest just picking a number like 32k or something easily divisible by 4, 8, or 16k. For example, if your block size is 8k, reading 32k will be 4 reads at the correct block size. If it's 16, then 2. But in each case, we're good because we happen to be reading an integer multiple number of blocks.

Comment: "while True" is quite pythonic.

Comment: In Python 3.8+ you can just do `while chunk := f.read(8192):`

Comment: is there a better way we can read the small chunks in parallel and get the hash, for better processing time/ performance if the file size is too big?

Comment: Is there an automatic way to set the block-size for ones disk?

Answer (score 54):

Here's my version of [Piotr Czapla's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131220/get-the-md5-hash-of-big-files-in-python/4213255#4213255):

```
def md5sum(filename):
    md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(128 * md5.block_size), b''):
            md5.update(chunk)
    return md5.hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 31):

Using multiple comment/answers for this question, here is my solution:

```
import hashlib
def md5_for_file(path, block_size=256*128, hr=False):
    '''
    Block size directly depends on the block size of your filesystem
    to avoid performances issues
    Here I have blocks of 4096 octets (Default NTFS)
    '''
    md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(path,'rb') as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(block_size), b''):
             md5.update(chunk)
    if hr:
        return md5.hexdigest()
    return md5.digest()
```

- This is [Pythonic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pythonic#Adjective)
- This is a function
- It avoids implicit values: always prefer explicit ones.
- It allows (very important) performance optimizations

Comment: One suggestion: make your md5 object an optional parameter of the function to allow alternate hashing functions, such as sha256 to easily replace MD5. I'll propose this as an edit, as well.

Comment: also: digest is not human-readable. hexdigest() allows a more understandable, commonly recogonizable output as well as easier exchange of the hash

Comment: Others hash formats are out of the scope of the question, but the suggestion is relevant for a more generic function.

I added a "human readable" option according to your 2nd suggestion.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how 'hr' is functioning here?

Comment: @EnemyBagJones 'hr' stands for human readable. It returns a string of 32 char length hexadecimal digits: https://docs.python.org/2/library/md5.html#md5.md5.hexdigest

Answer (score 10):

**A Python 2/3 portable solution**

To calculate a checksum (md5, sha1, etc.), you must open the file in binary mode, because you'll sum bytes values:

To be Python 2.7 and Python 3 portable, you ought to use the `io` packages, like this:

```
import hashlib
import io


def md5sum(src):
    md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with io.open(src, mode="rb") as fd:
        content = fd.read()
        md5.update(content)
    return md5
```

If your files are big, you may prefer to read the file by chunks to avoid storing the whole file content in memory:

```
def md5sum(src, length=io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE):
    md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with io.open(src, mode="rb") as fd:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: fd.read(length), b''):
            md5.update(chunk)
    return md5
```

The trick here is to use the [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) function with a *sentinel* (the empty string).

> The iterator created in this case will call *o* [the lambda function] with no arguments for each call to its `next()` method; if the value returned is equal to sentinel, `StopIteration` will be raised, otherwise the value will be returned.

If your files are **really** big, you may also need to display progress information. You can do that by calling a callback function which prints or logs the amount of calculated bytes:

```
def md5sum(src, callback, length=io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE):
    calculated = 0
    md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with io.open(src, mode="rb") as fd:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: fd.read(length), b''):
            md5.update(chunk)
            calculated += len(chunk)
            callback(calculated)
    return md5
```

Answer (score 5):

A remix of [Bastien Semene's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131220/get-the-md5-hash-of-big-files-in-python/17782753#17782753) that takes [the Hawkwing comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131220/get-the-md5-hash-of-big-files-in-python#comment26780341_17782753) about generic hashing function into consideration...

```
def hash_for_file(path, algorithm=hashlib.algorithms[0], block_size=256*128, human_readable=True):
    """
    Block size directly depends on the block size of your filesystem
    to avoid performances issues
    Here I have blocks of 4096 octets (Default NTFS)

    Linux Ext4 block size
    sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda5 | grep -i 'block size'
    > Block size:               4096

    Input:
        path: a path
        algorithm: an algorithm in hashlib.algorithms
                   ATM: ('md5', 'sha1', 'sha224', 'sha256', 'sha384', 'sha512')
        block_size: a multiple of 128 corresponding to the block size of your filesystem
        human_readable: switch between digest() or hexdigest() output, default hexdigest()
    Output:
        hash
    """
    if algorithm not in hashlib.algorithms:
        raise NameError('The algorithm "{algorithm}" you specified is '
                        'not a member of "hashlib.algorithms"'.format(algorithm=algorithm))

    hash_algo = hashlib.new(algorithm)  # According to hashlib documentation using new()
                                        # will be slower then calling using named
                                        # constructors, ex.: hashlib.md5()
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(block_size), b''):
             hash_algo.update(chunk)
    if human_readable:
        file_hash = hash_algo.hexdigest()
    else:
        file_hash = hash_algo.digest()
    return file_hash
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get its md5 without reading the full content. But you can use the *[update](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.update)* function to read the file's content block by block.

*m.update(a); m.update(b)* is equivalent to *m.update(a+b)*.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following code is more [Pythonic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pythonic#Adjective):

```
from hashlib import md5

def get_md5(fname):
    m = md5()
    with open(fname, 'rb') as fp:
        for chunk in fp:
            m.update(chunk)
    return m.hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like loops. Based on [Nathan Feger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131220/get-the-md5-hash-of-big-files-in-python/11143944#11143944):

```py
md5 = hashlib.md5()
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    functools.reduce(lambda _, c: md5.update(c), iter(lambda: f.read(md5.block_size * 128), b''), None)
md5.hexdigest()
```

Comment: What possible reason is there to replace a simple and clear loop with a functools.reduce abberation containing multiple lambdas? I'm not sure if there's any convention on programming this hasn't broken.

Comment: My main problem was that `hashlib`s API doesn't really play well with the rest of Python. For example let's take `shutil.copyfileobj` which closely fails to work. My next idea was `fold` (aka `reduce`) which folds iterables together into single objects. Like e.g. a hash. `hashlib` doesn't provide operators which makes this a bit cumbersome. Nevertheless were folding an iterables here.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of [Yuval Adam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131220/get-the-md5-hash-of-big-files-in-python/1131238#1131238) for [Django](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29):

```
import hashlib
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField()  # Any field based on django.core.files.File

    def get_hash(self):
        hash = hashlib.md5()
        for chunk in self.file.chunks(chunk_size=8192):
            hash.update(chunk)
        return hash.hexdigest()
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure that there isn't a bit too much fussing around here. I recently had problems with md5 and files stored as blobs in MySQL, so I experimented with various file sizes and the straightforward Python approach, viz:

```
FileHash = hashlib.md5(FileData).hexdigest()
```

I couldn’t detect any noticeable performance difference with a range of file sizes 2 KB to 20 MB and therefore no need to 'chunk' the hashing. Anyway, if Linux has to go to disk, it will probably do it at least as well as the average programmer's ability to keep it from doing so. As it happened, the problem was nothing to do with md5. If you're using MySQL, don't forget the md5() and sha1() functions already there.

Comment: This is not answering the question and 20 MB is hardly considered a *very big file* that may not fit into RAM as discussed here.

Answer (score -5):

```
import hashlib,re
opened = open('/home/parrot/pass.txt','r')
opened = open.readlines()
for i in opened:
    strip1 = i.strip('\n')
    hash_object = hashlib.md5(strip1.encode())
    hash2 = hash_object.hexdigest()
    print hash2
```

Comment: please, format the code in the answer, and read this section before giving answers: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: This will not work correctly as it is reading the file in text mode line by line then messing with it and printing the md5 of each stripped, encoded, line!