# MD5 hash differences between Python and other file hashers

Tags: python, hash, md5

I have been doing a bit of programming in Python (still a n00b at it) and came across something odd.  I made a small program to find the MD5 hash of a filename passed to it on the command line.  I used a function I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131220/get-md5-hash-of-a-files-without-open-it-in-python/1131255#1131255) on SO.  When I ran it against a file, I got a hash "58a...113".  But when I ran Microsoft's [FCIV](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290) or the md5sum.py in \Python26\Tools\Scripts\, I get a different hash, "591...ae6".  The actual hashing part of the md5sum.py in Scripts is

```
m = md5.new()
while 1:
    data = fp.read(bufsize)
    if not data:
        break
    m.update(data)
out.write('%s %s\n' % (m.hexdigest(), filename))
```

This looks functionally identical to the code in the function given in the other answer... What am I missing?  (This is my first time posting to stackoverflow, please let me know if I am doing it wrong.)

Comment: Where is `fp` created? Are you opening it in ASCII mode instead of Binary?

Comment: Ah ha! That was it.  I had not specified a mode parameter in the open() function in my program, so it was defaulting to text mode.  I set the mode to 'rb', and now it's returning the correct hash.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Already resolved in comments, but in case anyone wants to give me points... ;)

Open your file in binary mode!

```
f = open(path, 'rb')
```