# Checksum Calculation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, checksum

I want to calculate  checksum of a string of hexadecimal values such as `040102` answer will `7` in this case and more complex as `0a0110000a3f800000` its answer will be `AE`.

I found an online [link](https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-checksum-calculator/) that gives me answer i want but i need to write code for same in python but not getting the output i want.

Please help
Thank you in advance

Comment: Please share the code - see [ask].

Comment: @ack currently i don't have any code i was looking for some reference.

Comment: Does this help [How do I calculate the MD5 checksum of a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874598/how-do-i-calculate-the-md5-checksum-of-a-file-in-python)?

Comment: @itprorh66 in my case i have to just XOR the values

Comment: this site can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") and ["How do I ask and answer homework questions?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions "How do I ask and answer homework questions?") pages for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in which i can calculate checksum xor.

```
def HexToByte(hexStr):
    bytes = []
    hexStr = ''.join(hexStr.split(" "))
    for i in range(0, len(hexStr), 2):
        bytes.append(int(hexStr[i:i+2], 16))
    return bytes
```