# Get checksum value of a file and compare the value with the numbers present in the control file

Tags: python, checksum

I am new to Python.
My requirement is to calculate the checksum of file1.csv and compare the value with the checksum value provided in the file1.control file.

I am able to achieve the same using the Linux command in python. But now i have to do the same using python code or functions.

The value i am getting in control file is 23674523.

Can anybody please help me to achieve the same.

Comment: Can you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874598/how-do-i-calculate-the-md5-checksum-of-a-file-in-python

Comment: @vikashkumar... thanks for your response. The solution that you are suggesting will give the md5 value not the checksum and the value that its giving is something like 5cb81980fc31. I want exactly 23674523 this number  as checksum value from feed so that it can match with the checksum value provided in the control file.