# How to grab all files in a folder and get their MD5 hash in python?

Tags: python, md5

I'm trying to write some code to get the md5 of every exe file in a folder.

My problem is that I don't understand how to do it. It works only if the folder contains only one file. This is my code:

```
import glob
import hashlib
file = glob.glob("/root/PycharmProjects/untitled1/*.exe")

newf = str (file)
newf2 =  newf.strip( '[]' )
newf3 = newf2.strip("''")

with open(newf3,'rb') as getmd5:
    data = getmd5.read()
    gethash= hashlib.md5(data).hexdigest()
    print gethash
```

And I get the result:

```
a7f4518aae539254061e45424981e97c
```

I want to know how I can do it to more than one file in the folder.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`glob.glob` returns a list of files. Just iterate over the list using `for`:

```
import glob
import hashlib

filenames = glob.glob("/root/PycharmProjects/untitled1/*.exe")

for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, 'rb') as inputfile:
        data = inputfile.read()
        print(filename, hashlib.md5(data).hexdigest())
```

Notice that this can potentially exhaust your memory if you happen to have a large file in that directory, so it is [better to read the file in smaller chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3431838/918959) (adapted here for 1 MiB blocks):

```
def md5(fname):
    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(fname, "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(2 ** 20), b""):
            hash_md5.update(chunk)
    return hash_md5.hexdigest()

for filename in filenames:
    print(filename, md5(filename))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help !

Answer (score 2):

I think in the end, you're opening only one empty file. The reason for that is that you take the list returned by `glob` and remove the list markers in its string representation (and only at both ends of the string as you use `strip`. This gives you something like:

```
file1.exe' 'file2.exe' 'file3.exe
```

You then give this string to open that will try to open a file called like that. In fact, I'm even surprised it works (unless you have only one file) ! You should get a `FileNotFoundError`.

What you want to do is iterate on all the files returned by `glob.glob`:

```
import glob
import hashlib
file = glob.glob("/root/PycharmProjects/untitled1/*.exe")

for f in file:
    with open(f, 'rb') as getmd5:
        data = getmd5.read()
        gethash = hashlib.md5(data).hexdigest()
        print("f: " + gethash)
```