# Exiting a loop when last file is a duplicate of the current file

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, comparison

I've been trying to automate the process of downloading images from certain sites, and people told me to use Python. The website's pages are in the format `http://site/... /number.html`.

Piecing together things from different sources, I ended up with this-

```
import os
import urllib
from urllib import urlopen
import BeautifulSoup
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import requests
import re
import hashlib

def md5(fname):
    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(fname, "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
            hash_md5.update(chunk)
    return hash_md5.hexdigest()

url = input()
usplit = re.split('/|\.', url)
title = usplit[5]
volume = None

if (usplit[6][0] == 'v'):
    volume = usplit[6]
    chapter = usplit[7]
    pg_no = int(usplit[8])
else:
    chapter = usplit[6]
    pg_no = int(usplit[7])

if (volume is not None):
    mpath = ".\\" + title + "\\" + volume + "\\" + chapter
    if not os.path.isdir(mpath):
        os.makedirs(mpath)
else:
    mpath = ".\\" + title + "\\" + chapter
    if not os.path.isdir(mpath):
        os.makedirs(mpath)

while (1):
    flg = 0
    r = requests.get(url)
    if (r.status_code!=200):
        print "Exception: Access!"
        exit()
    print "Getting content from " + url
    html = r.content
    page = BeautifulSoup(html)
    image = page.findAll('img')[0]['src']
    res = urllib.urlopen (image)
    prevfile = mpath + "\\" + str(pg_no-1) + ".jpg"
    file = mpath + "\\" + str(pg_no) + ".jpg"
    if (not (os.path.isfile(file))):
        print "Writing to... " + file
        output = open(file,"wb")
        output.write(res.read())
        output.close()
        if (flg==1):
            if (md5(file) == md5(prevfile)):
                print "All done!"
                exit()
        print "Done."
    else:
        print str(pg_no) + ".jpg already exists, skipping..."
    flg = 1
    pg_no+=1
    if (volume is not None):
        newurl = usplit[0] + "//" + usplit[2] + "." + usplit[3] + "/" + usplit[4] + "/" + title + "/" + volume + "/" + chapter + "/" + str(pg_no) + "." + usplit[9]
    else:
        newurl = usplit[0] + "//" + usplit[2] + "." + usplit[3] + "/" + usplit[4] + "/" + title + "/" + chapter + "/" + str(pg_no) + "." + usplit[8]
    url = newurl
```

The problem is, after I reach the last image, the website redirects me to the last valid page. That is, if `46.html` is the last page, the request for `47.html` is redirected to it, and `r.status_code` remains the same.
To circumvent this, I tried to compare the last file downloaded, and the current file, and terminate the program. However, this does not seem to work. I am new to this, and unsure as to how to compare the files, and md5 function was something I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431825/generating-an-md5-checksum-of-a-file). I tried using `filecmp` too, but it doesn't seem to work either.

Any suggestions? Also, regarding the code, is there anything which could be made more Python-y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining `flg` repeatedly.
Put it out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the html content of these sites is not identical you could compare the content:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://site/... /46.html")
next = requests.get("http://site/... /47.html")
if r.content == next.content:
    print("Site visited already")
```

If you want to break the while loop, you can use the break statement.