# cap.isOpened() is returning false . I am using ubuntu but when I am using the same code in windows, I am able to execute

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

cap.isOpened() is returning false . I am using ubuntu but when I am using the same code in windows, I am able to execute

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('jitender.mp4')
count=0
print(cap.isOpened())
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    count=count+1
    print(count)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: maybe related? https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/14  at least in these bindings there is no FFmpeg support for Linux and MacOS yet.

Answer (score 0):

`isOpened` returns `False` when it cannot open the file or when it cannot understand the file it opened. Make sure:

- The file is in the same directory
- Your user has read permissions to the file
- The file is, in fact, the video file.

Try `ls -l jitender.mp4`. You should see something like:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 <username>  <group>  1234567 Nov 20 19:30 jitender.mp4
```

You might get `-rw-rw-rw-`, the important part is that you have the `r`'s there. You also need to make sure the number after your group name is sufficiently large. Sometimes files are corrupted in transit. If you can do some sort of checksum, that would let you know for sure. [Instructions for a checksum can be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431825/generating-an-md5-checksum-of-a-file)

Comment: below is  the ls -l output
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jitender jitender  1055736 Nov 21 21:34 abc.mp4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jitender jitender 44213366 Nov  9 16:29 jitender.mp4
 So I dont think read mode will be an issue