# How to use FileUploadHandler.upload_complete(self) callback for post-upload processing?

Tags: python, django, file-upload, callback

I'm new to python and I need to get the MD5 of a file that is uploaded through the script I'm using. The original scripts were written by this guy at this blog http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-filetransfers.

How can I utilize the upload completed callback to get the MD5?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1131255/534150

just use the MD5 algo in the uploaded file, and it should work!