# Python: Generating a MD5 Hash of a file using Hashlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, md5

I am trying to generate hashes of files using hashlib inside Tkinter modules.
My goal:

Step 1:- Button (clicked), opens up a browser (click file you want a hash of).
Step 2:- Once file is chosen, choose output file (.txt) where the hash will be 'printed'.
Step 3:- Repeat and have no clashes.

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import hashlib

def hashing():
    hash = askopenfilename(title="Select file for Hashing")
    savename = askopenfilename(title="Select output")
    outputhash = open(savename, "w")
    hash1 = open(hash, "r")
    h = hashlib.md5()
    print(h.hexdigest(), file=outputhash)
    love.flush()
```

It 'works' to some extent, it allows an input file and output file to be selected. It prints the hash into the output file.

HOWEVER - If i choose ANY different file, i get the same hash everytime.

Im new to Python and its really stumping me.

Thanks in advance.

---

Thanks for all your comments.

I figured the problem and this is my new code:

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import hashlib

def hashing():
    hash = askopenfilename(title="Select file for Hashing")
    savename = askopenfilename(title="Select output")
    outputhash = open(savename, "w")
    curfile = open(hash, "rb")
    hasher = hashlib.md5()
    buf = curfile.read()
    hasher.update(buf)
    print(hasher.hexdigest(), file=outputhash)
    outputhash.flush()
```

This code works, You guys rock. :)

Comment: Yes, as the hash you're getting is a hash of an empty string. Read the docs. You need to initialize the hash: `h.update(some_data)`.

Comment: you're not hashing your file at all. nowhere do you pass your selected filename to hashlib, so you're hashing a null value. and I'll bet the hash is `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`, which is what `md5('')` would return.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! So i looked further into it and with a little luck i found some old stuff. (look in main for new code)

Answer (score 4):

In your case you do the digest of the empty string and probably you get:
*d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e*

I used this method to digest, that is better for big files (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131220/get-md5-hash-of-big-files-in-python)).

```
   md5 = hashlib.md5()
   with open(File, "rb") as f:
       for block in iter(lambda: f.read(128), ""):
           md5.update(block)
   print(md5.hexdigest())
```

Comment: Thanks for using `rb` instead of `r`

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way

```
from hashlib import md5

f=open("file.txt","r")
data=f.read()
f.close()
Hash=md5(data).hexdigest()
out=open("out.txt","w")
out.write(Hash)
out.close()
```