# Chunked and Total MD5 Calculation in Python

Tags: python, md5

I have a large file which I will upload in chunks using Python. Each chunk will be ~4MB and the file could be quite large. I would like to (most efficiently) calculate an MD5 value for each of the chunks as well as an MD5 for the entire file. I fully understand how to calculate MD5 based on the [hashlib reference docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) and other stackoverflow questions on efficiently [calculating MD5 values for large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131220/get-md5-hash-of-big-files-in-python).

The easiest solution I see is to have a hashlib.md5() instance for each chunk and one for the total data. However, this means effectively running the md5 algorithm twice over the full data and doing a bunch of digesting. I can optimize this ever so slightly by calling copy() on the first hashlib.md5() value after it processes the first chunk, but after that point I don't see how to do this more effectively.

Is there a better way I can basically combine the MD5 values for each chunk into a total MD5 for the full file using Python?

Comment: have you profiled your code to see if this is actually any sort of bottle neck? I assume the disk access cost will dwarf the md5sum cost

Comment: It will, many things will dwarf the cost. But disk cost is not something I can change, and MD5 is. Between doing and not doing MD5 we do see a difference. If there's a way to optimize this, why not consider it?

Comment: bah fair point ... but no theres no way to combine md5's to get the same md5 the entire corpus returns

Comment: Figured that might be the case but I wasn't familiar enough with the MD5 algorithm itself to know if there was some way to hash components. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

you can modify the answer in the other thread you linked

```
def generate_file_md5(rootdir, filename, blocksize=2**20):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    with open( os.path.join(rootdir, filename) , "rb" ) as f:
        while True:
            buf = f.read(blocksize)
            if not buf:
                break
            m.update( buf )
            yield(hashlib.md5(buf).hexdigest())
    yield m.hexdigest()
```

this keeps a running md5 total for the whole file as it iterates so you are at least only iterating the file contents one time

(note that you would call this like)

```
md5s = list(generate_file_md5("/path/","file.txt",chunksize))
md5s[-1] # the whole file checksum
md5s[:-1] # the partial md5s
```

Comment: Going to give this a +1 since I appreciate the code as best effort (ie, doesn't do the impossible of reusing the chunk md5s's, but is probably best we can do) and I think it's valuable to have on StackOverflow. Then for posterity i'm going to mark my own question as a duplicate since I effectively found an answer that tells me what I want to do is not possible. :)