# Python equivalent of Perl Digest::MD5 functions

Tags: python, string, perl, encoding, md5

As part of a work project I am porting a Perl library to Python.  I'm comfortable with Python, much (much) less so with Perl.

The perl code uses [Digest::MD5](https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::MD5).  This module has three functions:

- `md5($data)`  takes in data and spits out md5 digest in *binary*
- `md5_hex($data)` takes in data and spits out md5 digest in *hex*
- `md5_base64($data)` takes in data and spits out md5 digest in base64 encoding

I can replicate md5_hex with something like this:

```
import hashlib
string = 'abcdefg'
print(hashlib.md5(string.encode()).hexdigest())
```

Which works fine (same inputs give same outputs at least).  I can't seem to get anything to match for the other two functions.

It doesn't help that string encodings are really not something I've done much with.  I've been interpreting the perl functions as saying they take an md5 digest and then re-encode in binary or base64, something like this:

```
import hashlib
import base64
string = 'abcdefg'
md5_string = hashlib.md5(string.encode()).hexdigest()
print(base64.b64encode(md5_string))
```

but maybe that's wrong?  I'm sure there's something fundamental I'm just missing.

The Perl doc is here:
https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::MD5

Comment: Clearly, you don't want to Base64 encode the hex representation of the hash, but the hash itself.

Comment: If you want to calculate the MD5 of big files, consider this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131220/get-md5-hash-of-big-files-in-python/40961519#40961519

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one would simply be calling `.digest` method on the `md5`:

```
>>> from hashlib import md5
>>> s = 'abcdefg'
>>> md5(s.encode()).digest()
b'z\xc6l\x0f\x14\x8d\xe9Q\x9b\x8b\xd2d1,Md'
```

And `md5_base64` is the digest but base64-encoded:

```
>>> base64.b64encode(md5(s.encode()).digest())
b'esZsDxSN6VGbi9JkMSxNZA=='
```

However, Perl doesn't return the hash padded, thus to be compatible, you'd strip the `=` padding characters:

```
>>> base64.b64encode(md5(s.encode()).digest()).strip(b'=')
b'esZsDxSN6VGbi9JkMSxNZA'
```

Comment: `md5(s.encode()).digest()` is equivalent to `md5` not `md5_hex`

Answer (score 0):

First, note [Digest::MD5](https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::MD5) documentation:

> Note that the base64 encoded string returned is not padded to be a multiple of 4 bytes long. If you want interoperability with other base64 encoded md5 digests you might want to append the redundant string "==" to the result.

Second, note that you want to Base64 encode the hash, not the hex representation of it:

```
print(base64.b64encode(hashlib.md5(string.encode()).digest()))
```

> `esZsDxSN6VGbi9JkMSxNZA==`

```
perl -MDigest::MD5=md5_base64 -E 'say md5_base64($ARGV[0])' abcdefg
```

> `esZsDxSN6VGbi9JkMSxNZA`

Comment: I chose Antti Haapala's answer because he also covered the binary case but this is very good for the base64 part.  Thank you!