# Python/Django upload in chunk, compute md5/sha1 on the fly in distributed system

Tags: python, django, md5, sha1, hashlib

I've a chunk upload system that allows people to upload a file in chunk. Now, at the end of the process I want to provide the md5 or sha1 of the whole file.

md5/sha1 have the property `update` which should work great in case of chunks, you just need to `update(content_of_the_chunk)` for every chunk.

The problem is: where and how I  should store the md5/sha1 object?

I'm using django, and i've several machine that handle the request. Such that I can't store the object in the session or in memory. I should put it in the database, but in the db I can only put the `hexdigest` (or a string) that then I can't sum or convert back to be used to do the `update`. How can I do?

Comment: Why can't you convert the hex string back to a number?

Comment: how? the only output that i've are digest, and from the digest you can't recompose back the text, thus it should not be able to go back and use the method `update` but maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: Do the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/q/1131220/621690 help? If you cannot use a shared file system/db then you might have to load the chunks into something like Redis or shared memory or similar.

Comment: which answer exactly? even with redis, what kind of data should i store? (the md5/sha1 does not support pickle)