# Why am I getting different hash for duplicated files?

Tags: python, hash, md5, hashlib

I need to check for duplicated and corrupted files in a folder with literally millions of files.

First, I was trying this way:

```
hash_files = pd.DataFrame({"Path":[],
                           "Hash":[]})

rootdir = "//?/Z:/"

error_files = []
for root, subdir, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    print(root)
    for filename in files:

        # String with file path
        source = root + "/" + filename

        with open(source, "rb") as file_obj:
            
            # File reading
            file_contents = file_obj.read() 
            file_obj.close()
            
        # Hash identification
        md5_hash = hashlib.blake2b(file_contents).hexdigest() 
        
        hash_files.loc[len(hash_files) + 1] = [source, md5_hash]
```

But the file reading part was taking too long to run in large files (and there are a lot). So I tried another way that seemed way quicker:

```
hash_files = pd.DataFrame({"Path":[],
                           "Hash":[]})

rootdir = "//?/Z:/"

error_files = []
for root, subdir, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    print(root)
    for filename in files:

        # String with file path
        source = root + "/" + filename  
            
        # Hash identification
        md5_hash = hashlib.blake2b(source.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        
        hash_files.loc[len(hash_files) + 1] = [source, md5_hash]
```

But in this last way, I'm getting different hash for duplicated files and I thought they had to be the same.

Anyone knows what is wrong or how I can get the right hash for all these files in a quicker way?

Comment: Your second solution is to take the hash of the file paths, that is obviously not an equivalent replacement for the hash of the file contents (I am quite sure you are not searching for duplicate file paths).

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you probably don't want to read large files entirely into memory; see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1131255/147356) for some thoughts on a more appropriate solution.

Comment: Where in your code is the check for duplicated and/or corrupt files? "Literally millions" of files in a single directory? Really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good case for multiprocessing.

The subprocesses should calculate the hash and return the Path and hexdigest.

Something like this will probably be as fast as you can possibly make it:

```
from hashlib import blake2b
from multiprocessing import Pool
from pathlib import Path, PosixPath
from typing import Iterator
from time import perf_counter

CHUNK = 64 * 1024
SRCDIR = Path("/Users/CtrlZ")


def process(path: Path) -> tuple[Path, str]:
    h = blake2b()
    with open(path, "rb") as f:
        while b := f.read(CHUNK):
            h.update(b)
    return path, h.hexdigest()


def getfiles(d: Path) -> Iterator[Path]:
    for e in d.iterdir():
        if e.is_file():
            yield e


def main():
    start = perf_counter()
    count = 0
    with Pool() as pool:
        result = pool.map_async(process, getfiles(SRCDIR))
        for p, h in result.get():
            print(p, h)
            count += 1
    duration = perf_counter() - start
    print(f"Processed {count} files in {duration:.2f} seconds")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks! I noticed if I increased the CHUNK value, than my code run faster. Should I be aware of a limit to use or can increase it more and more?

Comment: @user026 Each chunk will consume RAM so the value rather depends on how many subprocesses are running and how much RAM you have. There's no guaranteed optimum value but 64KB as used in this example may be too low. Try larger values and monitor your system's use of swap space. If it starts swapping then your chunk size is probably too high